# CEFSharp proprietary codecs support

Tags: c#, html, ffmpeg, chromium-embedded

I got an issue with CEFSharp which is chromium embeddable framework wrapper for C#.NET. I need to make proprietary codecs available for a project (H.264/MP4 to be specific). After some google-fu I've found that I must set the use_proprietary_codecs to true in the cef.gyp(i) file, but the problem is, that I've got this stuff from NuGet and there aren't any cef.gyp(i) files. I need this library badly to have the codec support, else we must rewrite 5 months of work completely, which isn't clearly an option. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Have you seen this one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35755197/951186?

Comment: not until yet, thanks for the heads up!