# how to set the support of mp3 and ffmpeg codec libraries to cef?

Tags: c#, ffmpeg, codec, chromium-embedded, cefsharp

I want to have cef lib with support of mp3 and ffmpeg codecs. How can i re-compile the library of cef with these codec features inside it.

I want to learn, where should I edit inside the cef library or cefsharp?
Then how to compile it to reuse it..

I am using cefsharp version 47.

Comment: How about searching the `GitHub` project?

Comment: I check git but when I try I get too many build problems and I need to learn about how to add mp3 and  ffmpeg codec support to cef build.

Comment: https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/1479

Comment: There are lots of other references as well, if you search `mp3` or `ffmpeg` it's hard to miss them!!!

Comment: @blgnklc did i answer your question?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**NOTE: PLEASE CONSIDER LEGAL ISSUES BEFORE PROCEEDING**

There is a way to enable MP3 support in CEF, but you'll have to modify the cef.gypi in the source distribution, regenerate the visual studio projects and rebuild.

Step by step instructions:

[image]
[image]
 `a`[image]
 [image]
`a`[image]
[image]

Comment: Its little big process..   :) @blgnklc

Comment: you may delete your account name for security propose. I will contact you when I have done it.  Igot your mail. thank you!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105681/discussion-between-blgnklc-and-null1941).

Comment: need to install cmake also :)

Comment: Thanks for this workaround, it was extremely useful, since i was able to build the nuget packages. I followed your guide step-by step but in the end when I referenced my custom nuget packages in cefsharp the CefSharp.WinForms.Example was still unable to open mpeg4/h264 video tags. I tried building the 2987 branch and based on the chromium   [wiki](https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/wiki/BranchesAndBuilding.md) i think the problem is that your guide is based on GYP constants but starting with the 2785 branch the automate script will use GN. Have you any clues about the GN constants?

Comment: @LeventePüsök GN Constants? Or GYP constants?

Comment: @null1941 GN Constants. I managed to find the available GN constants, in the [GN build documentation](https://www.chromium.org/developers/gn-build-configuration) and i used these additional constants:

`set CEF_USE_GN=1`
`set GN_DEFINES=is_official_build=true proprietary_codecs=true ffmpeg_branding=Chrome`

and it finally worked.

Comment: Hi I followed all the steps and was successfully able to build mp3 codecs. I am running into a problem where after compiling new cef binary into cefsharp I try to use the dll in my project but I dont see mp3 support in my project. Also my project depends on a library which bring CefSharp 55.0.0 as a dependency. Can somebody suggest what can I do

Answer (score 1):

See this SO question: [Chromium Embedded Framework MP3 support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8033495/chromium-embedded-framework-mp3-support)

It contains links to build instructions as well as the following:

> Codecs like MP3 and AAC are included in Google Chrome releases but not Chromium builds. This is because these formats are not open and require licensing. Distributing these codecs with your application without a licensing agreement may violate the law in certain countries. You should discuss with a lawyer if appropriate.

I suggest reading through the entire answer and related links.