# Enable AAC support in Chromium Embedded Framework (C#)

Tags: c#, spotify, chromium-embedded, aac

I've successfully registered widevine in my audio player, so I can log in to Spotify Web Player, but I can't play any audio track becuase the appropriate codec is still missing. As I know the web player is using AAC format so somehow I should add AAC support to CEF.

Have you guys got any idea how should I do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to set the support of mp3 and ffmpeg codec libraries to cef?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35664119/how-to-set-the-support-of-mp3-and-ffmpeg-codec-libraries-to-cef)

Answer (score 1):

You need a custom build of CEF with proprietary codecs enabled (use `proprietary_codecs=true ffmpeg_branding=Chrome` build flags).
You can find instructions for building CEF with codecs enabled here:
[Chromium Embedded Framework MP3 support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8033495/chromium-embedded-framework-mp3-support)

NOTE: If you want to use the custom build commercially, you need to consider legal issues for codecs.