# cefsharp how to add widevine .player bitmovin?

Tags: c#, vb.net, cefsharp, widevine

I added the cefsharp chrome browser in my program and it works perfectly. But I ran into a problem when I open a video player webpage and the screen remains black.

Are there additions that I add?

How do I compile to support the videos??

Comment: This question probably was a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49141848/cefsharp-browser-video-wont-play)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64293697/enable-aac-support-in-chromium-embedded-framework-c/64544434#64544434 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35664119/how-to-set-the-support-of-mp3-and-ffmpeg-codec-libraries-to-cef https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8033495/chromium-embedded-framework-mp3-support

Comment: I didn't reach anything