# CefSharp - CEF (Chromium Embedded Framework) - (6261) challenging to build

Tags: build, compiler-errors, cefsharp, chromium-embedded

I created this [setup](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/HEAD/docs/windows_build_instructions.md) before proceeding.

I've been trying to compile CefSharp with proprietary codecs for use in my C# Forms project for a year, but I'm faced with a pyramid of new errors with each new unsuccessful attempt.

So in short the first time following this [guide](https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/wiki/MasterBuildQuickStart.md) and [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35664119/how-to-set-the-support-of-mp3-and-ffmpeg-codec-libraries-to-cef/35755197#35755197) but I got stuck at "`create.bat`" --> `automate-git.py` step due to error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "automate-git.py", line 722, in <module>
    raise Exception('Not a valid git checkout: %s' % (chromium_src_dir))
Exception: Not a valid git checkout: c:\cef\chromium\src
```

So I solved it using this answer in this [thread](https://www.magpcss.org/ceforum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=19537#p54004), and it cost me another error that only appeared 14 hours later at the end of executing the update.bat step "following the [guide's](https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/wiki/MasterBuildQuickStart.md) order" but the terminal closed automatically and very quickly even though I ran update.bat through cmd (admin) and the error did not appear again when I ran the batch again without restarting the progress. But it basically said "`hook not found`" which I had removed from `update_depot_tools.bat` step as the previous thread I mentioned.

Currently I tried to compile from the master branch (currently 6261).

So I tested it on another computer with Windows 10 x64 recreating the same scenario and I had the same errors. So far I haven't found a way or an updated guide to compile CEF. I'm not stuck with CefSharp, alternatives are also welcome as long as they support video codecs.

Comment: CEF has it's own support forum at https://www.magpcss.org/ceforum/index.php If you need help building CEF then that's the place to search/ask.

Comment: I tried to create an account on the site, but I never received an email confirmation in my inbox and spam.

Comment: https://github.com/chromiumembedded/cef/issues/2962#issuecomment-1465023905