# CefSharp Browser Video Won't Play

Tags: c#, cefsharp

I'm using CefSharp Winforms x86 build. I want to play a video from this link :

```
http://developers.canal-plus.com/rx-player/
```

In google chrome it's working but my CefSharp WinForm Browser can't play any of these. I checked javascript is enabled. Am i missing something ? This page doesn't require any flash player. It's HTML5 player.

Comment: CEF, which is the base for CefSharp, does not support proprietary video formats (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29535637/cant-play-video-mp4-in-chromium-embedded-framework). Which video format is used at the site you linked in your question?

Comment: @Marius My video is mp4 so i guess i need h264 support but cef don't have that which i learned just now. Do you know any other way ? Extension for cef maybe ? I will search that now. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

CefSharp is based on CEF which is based on Chromium. Chromium does not support proprietary audio and video formats only Google Chrome does (see [Chromium documentation](https://www.chromium.org/audio-video)).

If you need proprietary codec support you need to [build CEF/Chromium on your own](http://magpcss.org/ceforum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=13515&start=40). There are no plugins/extensions which enable this functionality.

See also previous SO questions related to this topic [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28926102/cefsharp-proprietary-codecs-support) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43845493/how-to-enable-h264-support-in-cef3-latest-version) etc.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and found a walk around it!

I convert mp4 to gif using this [link](https://ezgif.com/video-to-gif) (you can disable the gif looping) and i extracted the audio out of the video and i played it synchronically using C#