# CefSharp Browser vimeo videos Won't Play

Tags: visual-c++, cefsharp

In my windows app, I use ChromiumWebBrowser, but when I Vimeo videos it doesn't work and keep loading also it works well google chrome, it tried to embed youtube videos and it works well

```
      public frmMain()
        {
            try
            {
                CefSharpSettings.LegacyJavascriptBindingEnabled = true;
                CefSharpSettings.ShutdownOnExit = true;
                CefSharpSettings.ShutdownOnExit = true;

                CefSettings cfsettings = new CefSettings();


                //set user agent, so back-end can recognise which app the student is using
                cfsettings.UserAgent = "Windows|" + WindowsAppVersion + "|app name |" + ProcessorArchitecture;

                Cef.Initialize(cfsettings);

                InitializeComponent();

                browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser(settings.StartURL)

                {
                    //full screen
                    Dock = DockStyle.Fill,

                };

                pnlBrowser.Visible = false;
                toolStripContainer.Visible = false;
                toolStripContainer.ContentPanel.Controls.Add(browser);

                browser.ConsoleMessage += OnBrowserConsoleMessage;
                browser.StatusMessage += OnBrowserStatusMessage;
                browser.TitleChanged += OnBrowserTitleChanged;
                browser.AddressChanged += OnBrowserAddressChanged;
                browser.FrameLoadEnd += browser_FrameLoadEnd;
                browser.MenuHandler = new CustomMenuHandler();

                browser.RegisterJsObject("winApp", new winApp(this));

            }
            catch (Exception E)
            {

            }
        }
```

Comment: Probably uses a non free audio/video codec see https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#multimedia-audiovideo for more details.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CefSharp Browser Video Won't Play](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49141848/cefsharp-browser-video-wont-play)

Comment: is there any alternatives?